# ASP.NET dynamic compilation with multiple web servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

Infrastructure:

- ASP.NET 4.6.1 website project (web forms)
- 2 web servers behind a load balancer
- Redis on AWS as session state provider

Issue:

Dynamic compilation occurs on each server, creating temporary asp.net files that have different names. Sometimes a postback will hit a different server than the previous request and I get a `FileNotFoundException` - `Could not load file or assembly 'PageName.aspx.551d078a.agzxzct4`. This file exists on the first server, but not the second.

Question:

How can I deploy my web forms website project to multiple web servers and allow each request to hit any server?

Ive tried:

- Precompiling with `aspnet_compiler`. I am using `VirtualPathProvider` so precompiling is out, per [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). I get a 404 on pages that use `VirtualPathProvider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an `enum` defined inside the code behind file. I just moved it to a separate class file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an ASP.NET website (not web application) project. While publishing the website project you can turn on the setting for merging pages and control outputs into a single assembly instead of creating a separate dll for each page which is default setting.

In the screenshot, on the publish dialog settings tab you can click on **Configure** link next to `Precompile during publishing option` and set `Advanced Precompile Settings`

[image]

Comment: This also precompiles though, which I cannot do because I'm using VirtualPathProvider, as per the docs above.